# WebFlux: How to Abstract-Out Method Returning Mono.error()

Tags: reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have a lengthy method that contains bunch of validation codes that will return `Mono.error()` when we found invalid objects.

```
   @Override
    public Mono<Item> update(Request item) {
        return itemRepository.findById(item.getId())
                .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new ResponseStatusException())
                .flatMap (item -> {

                    // bunch of validation ifs
                    if (..) {
                        return Mono.error(..);
                    }

                    return itemRepository.update(item);
                });
    }
```

How do I generify and extract these validation codes returning Mono.error?
I've tried the following but it is giving warning that i need to specify `Mono<Item>` instead of just `Mono`. I want to create a common method that will return for different types of Mono

```
private Mono validate() {
        // bunch of validation ifs
        if (..) {
            return Mono.error(..);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try with

```
private <R> Mono<R> validate(R itemToValidate) {
        if(...){
            return Mono.error(...);
        }
    }
```

Comment: how do you do this if its Mono<Void>? can you pls give an example